# Clarification needed what the presenter in the MVP pattern should know

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I'm trying to refactor a WindowsForm to the MVP Pattern. The app is a tile editor. The form has a custom control where i display the tilemap (TileDisplay). After loading a map from a file i call a method named "AdjustHScrollBar" to readjust the horizontal scrollbar to the tilemap-size. I'm not 100% sure how to split the method according to MVP.
First the original none MVP method:

```
private void AdjustHScrollBar()
{
    if (tileMap.GetWidthInPixels() > tileDisplay.Width)
    {
        hTileScrollBar.Visible = true;
        hTileScrollBar.Minimum = 0;
        hTileScrollBar.Maximum = tileMap.GetWidth();
    }
    else
    {
        hTileScrollBar.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This is the method after using MVP in the presenter:

```
private void AdjustHScrollBar()
{
    if (mainFormModel.TileMap.GetWidthInPixels() > mainFormView.GetTileDisplayWidth())
    {
        mainFormView.EnableHScrollBar(mainFormModel.TileMap.GetWidth());
    }
    else
    {
        mainFormView.DisableHScrollBar();
    }
}
```

The view doesn't know the presenter. My question is if the presenter should know the controls of the view. In my implementation it doesn't - that's the reason for the GetTileDisplayWidth, EnableHScrollBar and DisableHScrollBar - methods. Afaik that's the right way, but this seems to become a lot of work if i have to make a method for every property i need from the view. I have basicly the "same" code for the vertical scroll bar for e.g. (so that's 6 methods for readjusting the scroll bars).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the `Presenter` layer is to be able to communicate with the `View` layer without knowing the specifics of the view, i.e. anything to do with size, color,what type of view it is or any other properties.

Usually the `presenter class` will take the `view object` in it's constructor. Ideally you would have the `Adjust` method on the view and the presenter would call it directly, even more ideally you would do this through an interface rather than direct view class.

In your code you are accessing all of the view's properties and then trying to manipulate them through the presenter, you don't necessarily have to do that unless you have some sort of dependency on business logic. So you can do the whole operation on the `View` layer and then call it from the `Presenter`layer.

MVP involves a lot of code and that is the trade-off that you have to accept.

Comment: The reason i does this in the presenter is cause it depends on the model (tilemap size).

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this in the presenter:

```
public interface ITileMapView
{
    event EventHandler<string> TileMapFileLoaded;
    void OnTileMapLoaded(TileMapModel model);
}

public class TileMapPresenter
{
    private readonly ITileMapView view;

    public TileMapPresenter(ITileMapView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        view.TileMapFileLoaded += OnTileMapFileLoaded;
    }

    private void OnTileMapFileLoaded(object sender, string filename)
    {
        // Parse data from file
        // Populate model

        // Tell view
        view.OnTileMapLoaded(model); //Implement the 'AdjustHScrollBar' logic in the view
    }
}
```

The Presenter knows when and how to get data, and how to interpret the data. You should not let the Presenter engage in any view specific logic.